# Setting default URL when using rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

I think the new asset pipeline is messing up the CarrierWave default method. I have the file I would like to use as my default images stored as `app/assets/images/listing_defaults/default.png`.

In my Uploader, I have the following

```
def default_url
  "assets/listing_defaults/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
end
```

When I run my app, the image is browsable at that address (`localhost:3000/assets/listing_defaults/default.png`)

For some reason though, when I try to get the default image to show up in my view, I get nothing.

```
<p>
  <b>Images:</b>
  <ul>
    <% @listing.images.each do |image| -%>
      <li><%= image_tag image.image_url.to_s %></li>
    <% end -%>
  </ul>
</p>
```

Yet uploaded files seem to work fine. Any ideas?

By the way, I've tried setting my default_url to the following with no luck.

```
"#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/listing_defaults/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the leading forward slash:

```
"/assets/listing_defaults/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it! I was having the same problems.

I call it like so...
`user.avatar.tiny.url`

That will go to the default URL if the attachment doesn't exist :)

Answer (score 0):

I just put my image on assets/image folder, and on uploader file:

```
[version_name, "image_name.png"].compact.join('_')
```

view:

```
<%= image_tag @something.image_url%>
```